# How to set dark theme for pgadmin4 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, pgadmin-4

Is there any way to set dark theme in pgadmin4 for ubuntu 18.04 as the default white background is starining.

Comment: No, it is not possible as of now & ticket is already opened for the same https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3741

Answer (score 31):

On pgAdmin4 browser tab go to:

File > Preferences > Miscellaneous > Themes > Dark

[image: pgAdmin4 Dark theme]

Comment: Note that this works on Windows' pgAdmin (and probably all other OSes as well).